# Cyrillic encoding python 2.7 array

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, unicode, encoding

My code so far:

```
data = [(u'Rest', u'русский', u'фввв', u'vc'), (u'Rest', u'русский', u'фввв ', u'vc')]
print(data)
```

result:

```
[(u'Rest', u'\u0440\u0443\u0441\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439', u'\u0444\u0432\u0432\u0432', u'vc'), (u'Rest', u'\u0440\u0443\u0441\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439', u'\u0444\u0432\u0432\u0432 ', u'vc')]
```

I want the output to display the cyrillic characters, like so:

```
[('Rest', 'русский', 'фввв', 'vc'), ('Rest', 'русский', 'фввв ', 'vc')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because when we print out a list or tuple, the representation of the elements within the list is defined by the element's `__repr__` function, rather than its `__str__` function. To fix this, you can use the following to encode the strings and then decode the `repr()` of the list.

**Code:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
data = [(u'Rest', u'русский', u'фввв', u'vc'), (u'Rest', u'русский', u'фввв ', u'vc')]
print repr([tuple(x.encode(sys.stdout.encoding) for x in sl) for sl in data]).decode('string-escape')
```

**Out:**

```
[('Rest', 'русский', 'фввв', 'vc'), ('Rest', 'русский', 'фввв ', 'vc')]
```